# How to divide bootstrap body into floating containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, divide

I'm trying to divide the body of my webpage into different text parts, i.e. rectangles that would be separated and kinda float on the background. A good example would be a following website: http://www.index.hr/. 
How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is not a code making service, and writing the code from scratch is not encouraged. Have you done any research as to how you would approach this problem? I will not give out the entire code, but I will tell you to research `<div>` HTML elements and CSS `position`, `float` and `clear` properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not trying to get the code from scratch. I've already built a website with navbar, footer, gallery, sidebar, carousel, gallery and google map. 
I would just like too get some pointers on what i need to look into in order to divide the body in the best way possible since it has a lot of text, and want to make it more readable.

Comment: It would be useful to see the HTML you want to edit, since layout is something that should be done first when building a webpage. But as @BrainHappy stated, learn Bootstrap Grid, it will take you less than a day to master it, and you will know how to align elements on the page properly.

Comment: And yes I did a lot of research. the problem is that since I'm not sure how to handle this (or ask the question more prrecisely), it's difficult to find the adequate solution. That's why I used the linked website as an example.